# Multilevel Databases

Tags: database

i want to know about multilevel databses and security in multilevel databases, would you please give me some links about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

the best place to get *links* is search engine, like google. Just query: "multilevel databses" you will get some links.

Answer (score 0):

See [https://serverfault.com/questions/40462/what-is-a-multilevel-database.](https://serverfault.com/questions/40462/what-is-a-multilevel-database).

It also mentions security.